# Сайт не принимает обновление css файла

Tags: css, ubuntu

Подскажите что делать, пожалуйста. Я внеc изменения в css файл, перекинул измененный css файл на сайт через sftp, а сайт постоянно показывает старую его версию, я уже и вдс перезапускал - не помогает. что делать? Вдс на ubuntu

Comment: Очистите кэш браузера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Попробуйте перезагрузить страницу через <kbd>ctrl+f5</kbd>
- Проверьте путь к файлу

Answer (score 0):

Ваш браузер, скорее всего кэширует страницу, попробуйте воспользоваться другим или сбросить кэш в этом.